# Jquery class checking and changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I posted a question up yesterday that asked for some help on an image switching script I had written, thank you to all that helped me. I've extended the script and have run into a problem that I can't for the life of me spot where the problem is.

HTML:

```
<div id="feature-image">
    <h1><span>A random heading</span></h1>
</div>

<div id="feature-links">
    <a class="a1" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="a2" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="a3" href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

JS + Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#feature-links a').click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('a-active')) {
            return false;
        } else {

    var image = $(this).attr('class');

        switchToImg(image, function() {
            $('#feature-links a .a-active').removeClass('a-active'); 
            $('#feature-links .' + image).addClass('a-active');
        });
    }
});

function switchToImg(image){
    $('#feature-image').fadeOut('300', function(){
        $('#feature-image').css('background-image','url(images/main_' + image + '.jpg)');
        $('#feature-image').fadeIn('300');
    });     
};
```

In the script I check for a `click` on an `<a>` tag, each `<a>` tag has a class of (a1, a2, a3 etc.). Also, the active `<a>` has a class of 'a-active'.

I'm attempting to check if `a-active` is set with this:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('a-active')) {
    return false;
}
```

and cut the script there so that it doesn't fade in and out the same image. However, the image continues to fade in and out despite my return false on checking for the class `a-active` and returning false. I am sure the problem is in the section where I am using `.addClass` and `.removeClass` but my knowledge of Javascript and Jquery is to flaky for me to properly debug this.

Could someone cast a critical eye over this please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrectly passed an anonymous function to your `switchToImg()` function, which doesn't accept one.

Instead, try the following JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#feature-links a').click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('a-active')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var image = $(this).attr('class');

            switchToImg(image);
        }
    });

    function switchToImg(image) {
        $('#feature-image').fadeOut('300', function() {
            $('#feature-image').css('background-image', 'url(images/main_' + image + '.jpg)');
            $('#feature-image').fadeIn('300');
        });
        $('#feature-links a.a-active').removeClass('a-active');
        $('#feature-links .' + image).addClass('a-active');
    };
});
```

Tested in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rPFTd/1/).

**EDIT:** I removed the call to `.stop()`, it wasn't necessary and introduced a bug.

Comment: Thank you Greg! That has sorted my problem! :)

Comment: If you're interested, I tightened up my code in this jsFiddle revision: http://jsfiddle.net/rPFTd/3/.

Comment: I really appreciate you doing that, my code was uhm... how do I put this... amateur! That's actually given me an insight into dot notation that I've never really appreciated. Thank you (again!)

Comment: You mean the chainable aspect of jQuery? Yeah, it's pretty cool. Most jQuery functions return the same jQuery set they are called on, which means you can do a lot with just a few lines. Another name for this is a "fluent interface".

Comment: Also, you will notice that I 'cached' the results of my jQuery selectors in variables, and used the variables instead of re-selecting them. This saves the browser from having to do the same work twice, and makes things faster.

Comment: Yes, the chainable aspect, I'm far to set in my PHP ways to fully appreciate it (you can probably tell by my code). Just one question: The jsfiddle you posted on the revision code doesn't seem to set or remove the 'a-active' class... but nothing seems to have changed in the switchToImg function from your original answer.

Comment: If you want a brutal appraisal of the quality of your jQuery code, try using jQueryLint. It will pick up mistakes like not caching results of a selector very quickly! Another speed increase is to use the `$(selector, context)` overload of the jQuery function to restrict where the engine has to look to find something matching the selector.

Comment: The `switchToImg()` function is largely unchanged from my original answer - all I did was cache the `$('#feature-image')` selector in a variable, and utilise chaining. The last 2 lines are what remove the `a-active` class and set it on the element just clicked. FYI, I also did another version slightly different again: http://jsfiddle.net/rPFTd/7.

Comment: Talk about above and beyond the call of duty. Thanks Greg, you've taught me a great deal believe it or not! That last solution is very elegant, I like alot.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `$('#feature-links a .a-active')` to `$('#feature-links a.a-active')`.

Space between a and .a-active means you're trying to match descendants of <a> with class a-active.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector to filter out active class.

$('#feature-links a:not(.a-active)')